# Type tuple(string memory,string memory) is not implicitly convertible to expected type string storage

Tags: solidity

i am trying to access multiple string values, but dont know why i am getting this error?

```
error:Type tuple(string memory,string memory) is not implicitly convertible to expected type `string storage.`
```

code

```
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

contract Books{
    
    string  public Booksz;
    
     
    
    function addBooks( string memory _author, string memory _title) public  returns (string memory){
        return Booksz =(_author, _title);
    }
    
   
}
```

Comment: You can't save multiple `string`s in one `string`. Also you are tempting to return 2 `string` whereas your function returns one `string`

Comment: can you refactor?

Comment: Refactor what?!

Comment: can you show me right way

Answer (score 0):

```
pragma solidity >0.8.0;

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

contract Books{
    
    string[] public Booksz;
    
    function addBooks(string memory _author, string memory _title) public returns(string[] memory){
        return Booksz = [_author, _title];
    }
    
   
}
```